# ExpressCache not working after Windows 8 reinstall on Samsung Series 7 Gamer

Tags: windows-8, cache

I have a Samsung Series 7 Gamer laptop which came with Windows 8.  After doing a reinstall of Windows, the ExpressCache software is no longer caching.

Running "eccmd -info" shows me that the software is present and it has the MSATA drive partition configured.  However, it's not actually caching anything.  These are the results after having the system booted for days:

```
C:\windows\system32>eccmd -info
ExpressCache Command Version 1.0.94.0
Copyright⌐ 2010-2012 Condusiv Technologies.
Date Time: 11/3/2013 12:26:20:263 (JAMETHIEL #36)

EC Cache Info
==================================================

Mounted                   : Yes
Partition Size            : 7.46 GB
Reserved Size             : 3.00 MB
Volume Size               : 7.46 GB
Total Used Size           : 86.50 MB
Total Free Space          : 7.38 GB
Used Data Size            : 16.63 MB
Used Data Size on Disk    : 84.38 MB

Tiered Cache Stats
==================================================
Memory in use             : 32.00 MB
Blocks in use             : 136
Read Percent              : 0.02%


Cache Stats
==================================================
Cache Volume Drive Number : 1
Total Read Count          : 97242
Total Read Size           : 4.13 GB
Total Cache Read Count    : 0
Total Cache Read Size     : 595.50 KB
Total Write Count         : 161546
Total Write Size          : 5.89 GB
Total Cache Write Count   : 0
Total Cache Write Size    : 0 Bytes

Cache Read Percent        : 0.01%
Cache Write Percent       : 0.00%
```

As you can see on the last two lines, cache read and write percent is nigh on zero.  Anyone know where to look next?  The only guides I can find deal with ExpressCache not being present or not having a configured drive.

Comment: restore the factory image where the OEM configured all software correctly and only remove the pre-installed trial versions of other tools.

Comment: I should have been clearer -- that's exactly what I did when I said "reinstall of  Windows".  I restored from the factory partition that reinstalls all software configured by Samsung.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same laptop and the SSD no longer shows up in the list of drives.

Answer (score 0):

You must have two partitions - 7.46 GB and another one same as your computer RAM size. You can see your partitions by running these commands in Cmd
diskpart
select disk 2(ssd)
list partition

- The 8G Partition is used for an OS copy for faster boot from hibernate or sleep states. But your partition is empty. So it's a valid concern that Windows 8 may have higher requirements and can't accept a 8 GB express cache (my windows8 used a whooping 14GB of expresscache)

-The second one is like SWAP memory. This will be empty only if you are not running some HPC applications in your desktop.

The last two lines are not ur concern at all! These will be low...
Under cache stats, you see this line:
 Total Read Size           : 4.13 GB
So, cache is accessed but mainly SWAP memory accesses and you don't see your partition here.

Where to look next? Check the expresscache requirements for Windows 8, as I said you may end up wasting a lot of time gaining nothing because u have inadequate expresscache for Windows 8 (may be ok for windows 7). I am sure you have to look into the most detailed manual and you will get your answer for sure! Good luck...